# ClickOnce deployment error on upgraded .NET application

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, deployment, clickonce

I have a Windows forms application that was developed in Visual Studio 2005 and deployed to an IIS server via ClickOnce. I've upgraded to VS2008 so I decided to upgrade and redeploy the application (in test). I ran the upgrade wizard, manually changed the project's target runtime to 3.5, removed all of the old publish files from the deployment server, and published the application.

I can launch it with no problem (i.e., "works on my machine"), but when others launch it they get an error.

> Cannot continue. The application is improperly formatted. Contact the application vendor for assistance.

There's a Details... button on the error dialog. Here are some of the contents.

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 5.1.2600.131072 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 2.0.50727.1433
System.Deployment.dll       : 2.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
mscorwks.dll            : 2.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
dfdll.dll           : 2.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
dfshim.dll          : 2.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
```

Note that the CLR is 2.0.

```
ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of http://{deployment host name}/ resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Exception reading manifest from http://{deployment host name}/{application name}.application: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
    + Manifest XML signature is not valid.
    + No signature was present in the subject.
```

I didn't sign the application. It's a completely internal departmental application. I suspect that the problem isn't the lack of a signature, it's that .NET is using the wrong runtime, and that the 2.0 runtime can't handle the 3.5 manifest. But if that's the case, I can't figure out how to get it to use the 3.5 runtime.

I thought maybe the older version was cached, so I had the user run `rundll32 %windir%\system32\dfshim.dll CleanOnlineAppCache`. That cleared the cache (the application did a full reload the next time), but it didn't solve the problem.

Has anybody had a problem like this upgrading a ClickOnce app from 2.0 to 3.5? Any idea what my problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

Please verify that you have .NET Framework 3.5 set as a prerequisite.

Project Settings -> Publish -> Prerequisites

Comment: Good suggestion. I updated the prerequisites to 3.5. Unfortunately we're getting same result.